# Ruby - watch for file with extension being updated

Tags: ruby, bash, less

I am trying to auto compile my less files on centos.

Is it possible in ruby to watch a directory for changes to files ending in a specific extension and then execute a command when that happens?

I have tried inotify in a simple shell script but there are always problems when an ide creates temporary files etc.

Comment: Search for `rb-inotify`

Answer (score 3):

You want `inotify`. A Ruby wrapper, [rb-notify](https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify), is available.

Answer (score 0):

The [ZenTest](https://github.com/seattlerb/zentest) gem includes the `autotest` command-line tool, which watches a test directory and runs tests when one of the files changes.

Go look at how that tool works. Using inotify is helpful but not necessary.

The basic idea for this is to write a `loop` with a `sleep` inside it. Use Ruby's [Find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class to locate the files that are candidates for processing. The Find documentation has example code to get that part started.